# How to show if following or not Vue Js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to create a follow button, already wrote the code, so when the user follows, it goes straight to the database, the user id and the followed user id, in the component, i wrote a code that check if the user is already being followed to return true and false and then if following is true should display following and vice versa, but so far whenever the page loads it shows followed when true , if i go to another page and come back, it go backs to showing follow which is false, till i refresh the entire page again

```
 <template>
  <button v-bind:class="{followVendor:!following,followingVendor:following}"  
      type="button"
            @click="followToggle"
        class=" btn btn-sm btn-outline">
        {{followText}}</button>

</template>



data:{
  userFollowing:{},
  following: false,
  followText:'follow',
 }

mounted(){
  axios.get(`/api/user-following`,
    {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.user.access_token}` }
    }).then(
        response=>{
            if (response.status === 200) {
                this.userFollowing = response.data;
                this.writer=true;

                if (this.userFollowing.length > 0) {
                    if (this.userFollowing[0].user_id === this.user.id && this.userFollowing[0].vendorId === this.writterD.id) {
                        this.following = true;
                        this.followText = 'following';
                }
                }
            }


        }
    )
}

 methods: {

follow(params, name) {

  let data = {
    vendorName: name,
    vendorId: params
  };
  if (this.auth) {
    axios
      .post("/api/user-following", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)), {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token}` }
      })
      .then(response => {


        if (response.status === 201) {
           this.following = true;
           this.followText = 'following';
          this.$toasted.success("Successfully followed");
        } else if (response.data === " Already following") {
          this.$toasted.error("Already following");
        } else {
          this.$toasted.error("Error");
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  } else {
    this.$toasted.error("You have to log in to follow");
  }
},
unFollow(){

    let vendor = this.writterD.id;
   let unfollow = confirm(`unfollow ${this.writterD.storeName}?`)
   if (unfollow) {

    axios.delete(`/api/user-following/${vendor}`,
    {headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token}`}}).
    then(response=>{

    if (response.status === 200) {
         this.following = false;
         this.followText = 'follow';
          this.$toasted.success("Successfully Unfollowed");

        }else{
             this.$toasted.error("Already Unfollowed");
        }

    })
   }

},
 followToggle(){
            this.following? this.unFollow(): this.follow(this.writterD.id, this.writterD.storeName);
    },
 }
```

how can i make it always show the right one even if i don't reload the entire page please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is force a rerender, the best way to do this is place a `key` on the component you need to update and then change the key when the info is updated. When the key is updated the data will update as the component will rerender. Like this:

```
<button :key="update" v-bind:class="{followVendor:!following,followingVendor:following}"  
      type="button"
            @click="followToggle"
        class=" btn btn-sm btn-outline">
        {{followText}}</button>
    ...
    data(){
       return {
           update: 0
    }
}
...
    this.followText = 'following';
    this.update++
```

See here for a nice article on the topic:
https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render

Comment: i saw something like this one time, never really understood it, Thanks let me give it a try